# Grouping Items in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, grouping

I'm not really sure how I would go about coding this but here's what the GridView should look like:

[image]

Items will be grouped according to their respective "products"

Any help regarding the structure of the GridView would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: check this out: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

Comment: thanks, naveen! i'll try and apply that! :)

Comment: btw, there are like 10 others exactly questions in stackoverflow... just use the search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control. It's way more customizable than GridView

Answer (score 0):

You could add a group by clause to your query from which you get the items in your gridview. This should get almost your desired output. Except the blank product rows.